# requests doesn't seem to connect and return data from a service but browser does

Tags: python, python-requests

Both the `service` and the `program` are running under `Ubuntu`.

I have an application that calls a `service` that returns a `json pandas dataframe`. The service prints out the data to the screen before serving the data.

I have tested the service using a browser, and it works great - I see the `jsonified` data in the browser. However, if I try to call the `service` using `requests` from a `python` program, it goes into a black hole and nothing ever comes back. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
def get_RRDf(ticker, date_years_ago, wind):
    print("Entering get_rrDf")

    build_params = "thresh=.20&symbol=" + ticker +"&window=" + str(wind) + "&lookback=5"
    api_url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/RR/"+build_params
    print(api_url)

    app_headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0' }

    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=app_headers)
    print("==================")
    print(type(response))
    print(response.text)
    print("==================")

    ...
```

Comment: difficult to help without the url. the code looks fine... can you access the url on browser from Ubuntu? Asking as there was a recent update on Ubuntu blocking internet connection if you use VPN etc...

Comment: Je Je that actually helped alot. I changed the IP address to a local LAN address, and now it works! Bizzare, it might be the VPN! I just don't understand how coming from the outside through a browser does work....

Comment: I haven't resolved the issue my side, but ap[parently linked to Proton VPN, if that what you use....

Comment: make sense? not to me.. : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04